# Karma - Maven plugin fails

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to integrate Karma with Maven using the 1.6 plugin but it fails and states that:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-karma-plugin:1.6:start (default) @ amm ---
[INFO] Executing Karma Test Suite ...
cmd /C C:\Dev\Workspaces\projectname\subname/src/main/webapp/node_modules/.bin/kar
ma start C:\Dev\Workspaces\projectname\subname\src\main\webapp\karma.conf.js --bro
wsers Chrome, Firefox --single-run --no-auto-watch --colors true
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Here are my settings in the maven `pom.xml`:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.kelveden</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-karma-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <karmaExecutable>${ammWorkspaceDir}/src/main/webapp/node_modules/.bin/karma</karmaExecutable>
                <configFile>${ammWorkspaceDir}/src/main/webapp/karma.conf.js</configFile>
                <browsers>Chrome, Firefox</browsers>
                <autoWatch>false</autoWatch>
                <singleRun>true</singleRun>
                <colors>true</colors>
                <skipKarma>false</skipKarma>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <karmaFailureIgnore>false</karmaFailureIgnore>
                <!-- <reporters>dots,junit</reporters> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I did a check using the cmd `dir` to see if the `node_modules` folder contains the `.bin` folder but it only contains:

```
karma
karma-chrome-launcher
karma-firefox-launcher
karm-jasmine
```

Where is the `.bin` folder? Note that I can run all the normal tests but I have to navigate to where the `karma.conf.js` file is to run them and can run the tests using `karma start` (they all pass).

So why is this failing? Is karma installed in the wrong place? Should `node` and such be present as a `System variable`?

Thanks

Comment: Did you install using the -g flag?

Comment: @zogTheDog Yes I tried to do that using the npm install -g karma command - then tried testing the install using karma --version. It complains that it cant find the local karma install. This suggests to me that karma isn't installing correctly. To get my tests to run I have to install karma to the local project folder (which seems to be recommended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. What was causing the build issue was the fact that the karma `node_modules` was interfering with the build. To get around this I had to remove the `node_modules` from the `webapp` folder and move it into the root directory of the project, as well as the `karma.conf.js` file.

That was the first part - the second part was to install karma globally using this command:

```
npm install -g karma && npm install -g karma-cli
```

By doing this you should beable to run karma from anywhere but that wasn't the case for me and I still don't know why (elaborate anyone?). The final part was in the actually maven `pom.xml`:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.kelveden</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-karma-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <configFile>karma.conf.js</configFile>
                <browsers>Chrome</browsers>
                <autoWatch>false</autoWatch>
                <singleRun>true</singleRun>
                <colors>true</colors>
                <skipKarma>false</skipKarma>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <karmaFailureIgnore>false</karmaFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The key point above is that I haven't included the `<karmaExecutable>` command here because if you include that then it will break - by keeping it out it will turn to the global karma install to run the tests in the Maven build. This worked for me - hope it works for you.

Comment: Kudos for following through with your own answer when you figured it out. You could have moved on and forgotten about this, but you made sure to give the information to save others time. Thank you!